# Placement-new on array elements and pointer values

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following three programs:

```
// program 1

#include<new>

struct A {
    const int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto a = new A[2];
    new(a+1) A;
    a[1].b = 1;
}
```

```
// program 2

#include<new>

struct A {
    const int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto a = new A[2];
    new(a) A;
    a[0].b = 1;
}
```

```
// program 3

#include<new>

struct A {
    const int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto a = new A[2];
    new(a) A;
    a->b = 1;
}
```

Do these programs have undefined behavior in C++17?

The problem I see is that according to [[basic.life]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#life-8) pointers will not automatically refer to the new `A` objects that I am creating via placement-new. `std::launder` is required explicitly to achieve that. Thus the member access will have undefined behavior as it is done on an object outside its lifetime.

At least for program 3 this seems clear to me, but for program 1, according to [[intro.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro#object-2) the newly created object becomes a subobject of the array and so it should be reached via pointer arithmetic, shouldn't it?

And program 2 would then also not have undefined behavior, because the pointer arithmetic only requires `a` to point to an element of the array, not necessarily in its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [[basic.life]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#life-8.3)

> the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and

Is the only clause that makes your member access code undefined behavior.

In all three cases `a` is the name of an array of two `A` objects so the member access is okay because you are using an `A` pointer to access an `A` object.  You're not treating a char buffer as an `A`, you treating an `A` as and `A` which is allowed.

Comment: @walnut Right, it's 8.3 which is the reason.  If 8.3 didn't exist, then I assert all of the code is legal.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood your answer. But then why does `a[1]` not refer to the new object in program 1? It seems to be a subobject and therefore element of the array and so by [expr.add/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4) that would be reached? Would you think that `std::launder(a)[1]` will refer to the new object?

Comment: @walnut `a[1]` is `*(a + 1)`.  `(a + 1)` is a pointer to the original object.  You can't use that pointer though because of 8.3.

Comment: I'm not sure if launder can be used to subvert this rule.

Comment: So in your interpretation the new object never becomes "*element*" of the array or at least pointer arithmetic will always yield a pointer to the original object.

Comment: @walnut That's my interpretation.  We'll see if others agree.

Comment: `std::launder` is used in this precise scenario, see [note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8).